# Class Average- Java

Tags: java, methods

I need a java application that Write a Java application which performs the following tasks:

1.Prompts the user for the number of students in the class

2.Using a for loop, asks the user to enter a grade for each student. You will need to maintain a sum of all of the grades.

3. Displays the class average to the user.

I need the following methods:

### public static int obtainNumberOfStudents()

This method will prompt the user for the number of students in the class and return the 
users input

### public static double obtainGrade()

Th
is method will prompt the user for a grade and return the users input.

### public static double calculateClassAverage(double sum, int numStudents)

Given the sum of all grades for the class and the number of students in the class this 
method will computer and 
return the class average

Any advice will help. Thanks!

This is my own code, which doesn't work. import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Assignment6 
{
    public static int obtainStudents(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many students");
        int students = input.nextInt();
        return students;
        }

    public static double obtainGrade(int students){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double grade = 0.0;
        for(int i = 0; i <=students; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Grade");
            grade = input.nextInt();
            grade+=grade;
            return grade;
        }
        return grade;



    }
    public static double calculateClassAverage(int students, double grade){

        double avg = grade/ students;
        System.out.println(avg);

    return avg;
    }


public static void main (String [] Args){

    calculateClassAverage(obtainStudents() , obtainGrade(0));

}
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything before asking on SO?

Comment: can you tell what all you have tried this far ? We cannot help you unless you do effort from your side.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework dump.

Comment: And what is your contribution so far apart from copy-pasting your homework here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only see one error here:

In your `obtainGrades` method, you return the grade in the for loop *and* outside the for loop, which means, the second `return` statement will be executed if and only if the for loop doesn't get executed and that is impossible. Your biggest problem is in the `obtainGrades` method.

Let me give you some pseudocode (and some real code):

First, you prompt the user for the number of students and store the input in a variable, let's call it `studentCount`. Next, create an array of length `studentCount`:

```
double[] studentGrades = new double[studentCount];
```

And you use a for loop to loop through the array and call `obtainGrades` in the loop and store the inputs in the array:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < studentCount ; i++) {
    studentGrades[i] = obtainGrades ();
}
```

Oh and by the way, `obtainGrades` should prompt the user for *one* grade and should not have a parameter.

```
public static double obtainGrades () {
    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    //code to prompt the user has been omitted...
    return Double.parseDouble (s.nextLine());
}
```

Now using the array, you can ad them together and do an average and stuff.